# jquery ajax - how does this work in relation?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around something.

If I open a URL manually in a browser window the cookies for that URL are used. If, however, I use the jquery ajax functionality to make requests to the same URL (even from a local html\javascript file) the same cookies are not used.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Why or why not?

Comment: Have you had a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+cookies ?

Comment: Why do you want that? You could send a URL-parameter telling your server script to ignore cookies. As the browser sends the cookies, you could [remove the cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.cookie) prior sending the ajax query and restore it later on. But I think that's sort of akward.

Comment: @Felix, I'm just looking for a general explanation of how or why this works (or doesn't). Of the 312 questions that are there now they mostly look like specific instances of questions - not a general overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost assuredly a cross-domain restriction.  If I have a script that is served from domain.com it can only make AJAX requests to domain.com.  When I attempt to make a request to "another-domain.com", the browser will NOT send cookies along with the request, and when the result is ready, will not give that result to my script.

The same is true of local files.  Scripts from local files can not successfully make requests to any domain.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the same cookies are being used during a ajax call as the ones being used if manually entering the url as long as the ajax request is coming from the same domain. If the request isnt coming from the same domain the cookies wont be used as its a cross domain sand box issue.